# Java co.elastic/org.elasticsearch libraries difference

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api-client

In Java, I can see there are 2 clients to work with elasticsearch: [co.elastic](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/co.elastic.clients/elasticsearch-java/7.17.3) and [org.elasticsearch](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch.client/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client/7.17.11). I am not counting `spring-data-elasticsearch` here or any other top-level abstractions.

These 2 libraries seemed to have very similar API, and even the class names are the same, but in different packages, like: `SearchRequest`, `SearchResponse`, `ElasticsearchClient` e.t.c. It also seems that `co.elastic` includes `org.elasticsearch` library. So I really do not understand:

1. What is the purpose of one library and what is the purpose of the other?
2. What library we can assume to be a "native" client for elasticsearch?
3. Since `co.elastic` includes the `org.elasticsearch`, I assume there is a dependency between those 2 projects. It would be great if anyone will clear this dependency as well.

I did not manage to find the exact answer I am looking for, so I am posting question here.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, while all other libraries were under the Apache 2.0 licence, the elastic HLRC (High Level Rest Client) has been under the Elastic licence until version 7.17, [because the HLRC has dependencies on the core of Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/pricing/faq/licensing#elasticsearch-api-how-affect-me).

Then [the Java HLRC has been deprecated in 7.15.0 in favor of the Java API Client. The Java API Client is licensed under Apache 2.0.](https://www.elastic.co/pricing/faq/licensing#elasticsearch-api-how-affect-me)

It's why it's the last version of HLRC available in this [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch.client/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client) link.

So to me it's all a matter of licencing summarized with this picture. [image: Elastic chart licence update 2021]